# Need help with these two probability questions!

Tags: probability

[image]

For the first question doesn't it depend on if a and b are disjoint or not so if they are disjoint the we have P(A) and if they are not disjoint then we have **P(A only)** so how do we answer this when they ask us to find a general expression like this **what do we assume about a and b? are they disjoint or not?**

For the second question i wanted to check if b is a subset of a is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you can draw a Venn diagram to help your intuition. If we imagine the area in common in the sets $A\cup B$ and $A \cup \overline{B}$ we find that we are left with exactly $A$ regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint or not.

We find therefore that:

$$(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup \overline{B})=A$$

As we can see in the following diagram ($A_{1}=A$ and $A_{2}=B$):

[image]

For the second one we can consider the definition of conditional probability:

$$\mathrm{P}(A \mid B)=\frac{\mathrm{P}(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Therefore we have:

$$P(A \cap B)=P(B)$$

And thus $A \cap B = B$, therefore we can say $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: if they are disjoint the we have P(A) and if they are not disjoint then we have P(A only) which doesn't include the intersection probability so aren't they different ?

Comment: If they are disjoint then the area in your Venn diagram $A$ is highlighted in both $A \cup B$ and $A \cup \overline{B}$ and therefore if you take the intersections of both these areas, you are left with the entirety of the area $A$.

Comment: i understand when they are disjoint but when they intersect the area isn't the whole of A, it is only A which doesn't include the intersection

Comment: @user134785 I've added a picture to help demonstrate, hope it helps!